# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision.transforms.functional'; 'torchvision.transforms' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, raspberry-pi4, torchvision, yolov5

Im currently perfoming A object detection using Rasperrypi model 4B 8 GB ram.The Error is

Code :
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import uuid
import os
import time
import torchvision as TF
import torch

model=torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5','custom',path='last1.pt',force_reload=True)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while cap.isOpened():
ret, frame = cap.read()

```
# Make detections
results = model(frame)

# Convert the results to a format compatible with cv2.imshow
rendered_results = np.squeeze(results.render())
rendered_results = rendered_results.astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imshow('YOLO', rendered_results)

if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

**Output Error**
import torchvision.transforms.functional as TF
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision.transforms.functional'; 'torchvision.transforms' is not a package

Help me with to perform the object detection using Pytorch